# Creating map of pacific with cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm trying to plot a map of the Pacific with Japan and California in view, but am having some problems.

Here's my script:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.set_extent([-110, -180, 30, 55], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    geodetic = ccrs.Geodetic()
    plate_carree = ccrs.PlateCarree()

    # Japan info
    lat_jap, lon_jap = plate_carree.transform_point(36.204823, 138.252930, geodetic)
    # California info
    lat_cal, lon_cal = plate_carree.transform_point(36.778259, -119.417931, geodetic)

    # Plot map markers for Japan and California
    ax.plot(lon_jap, lat_jap, markersize=10, marker='o')
    ax.plot(lon_cal, lat_cal, markersize=10, marker='o')

    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which produces:

[image]

I'm getting close, but when I decrease the `x2` argument passed to `set_extent` beyond -180, the map seems to flip and plot the extent in the opposite direction. Why does this happen?

I am also trying to plot markers on Japan and California, and try to convert between the lat/lon coordinates in degrees to points on the plate carree system, but that also doesn't seem to work.

As a final touch, I want to draw a great circle line between the two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a runnable code. Read comments in the code for information.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,7))

    # this declares a recentered projection for Pacific areas
    usemap_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)
    usemap_proj._threshold /= 20.  # to make greatcircle smooth

    ax = plt.axes(projection=usemap_proj)
    # set appropriate extents: (lon_min, lon_max, lat_min, lat_max)
    ax.set_extent([125, 280, 25, 55], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    geodetic = ccrs.Geodetic()
    plate_carree = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)

    # Japan info
    lon_jap, lat_jap = 138.252930, 36.204823
    # California info
    lon_cal, lat_cal = -119.417931, 36.778259

    # Plot map markers for Japan and California
    ax.plot(lon_jap, lat_jap, markersize=10, marker='o', color='red', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.plot(lon_cal, lat_cal, markersize=10, marker='o', color='brown', transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    # plot greatcircle arc
    gcc = ax.plot([lon_jap, lon_cal], [lat_jap, lat_cal], color='blue', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

    ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND, color='lightgray')
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
    ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
    # plot grid lines
    ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), color='gray', linewidth=0.3)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: jpn_usa]

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure I understand, is the issue of the map flipping around because of the default `central_longitude` value? And by setting that, you can expand the longitudes shown relative to that location?

Comment: @Mike You are correct. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856123/setting-up-a-map-which-crosses-the-dateline-in-cartopy